# Android button shadow/margin top

Tags: android, button, shadow

I have a Button and an ImageView in one line. But Button has margin to top. And I use a simple background drawable.

Part of XML Code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:background="@color/main_green"
        android:text="@string/from"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_white"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fromCityButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="From"
        android:background="@drawable/button_blank_border"/>    

</LinearLayout>
```

Button background drawable code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/main_background"/>
            <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Now this part looks like this:
[image]

But it should look like this:
[image]

How should I fix that shadow/margin of the button?

Comment: You can use the liner layout and provide the weightSum attibute in it

Comment: Read all the question. The Button part is a little down from the TextView part. And that's the issue.

Comment: Add `android:gravity="center"` in linearlayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#008080"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"  <--------
        android:text="IS"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="22dp" />
```

Comment: Gravity to TextView doesn't make any difference. But this line to LinearLayout fixes the problem.

Comment: Nice eyes just a copy of his. Make necessary changes